# Display jsstore values in html after fetching data using select command ?

Tags: angular, ionic2, indexeddb

Brief explanation -> I used 'select' Api to select data from a database.

home.ts code->

```
var connection = new JsStore.Instance();
      var dbName = 'Demo';
  connection.openDb(dbName);

  connection.select({
    from: tblnm,
  }).then(function(results) {
 // results will be array of objects

    console.log(results,'result');

  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err, 'error');
    alert(err.message);
});
```

It returns an array

> {User: "KIRAN", mytask: 1, allocation: 4, follower: 5}

how to use this returned value in html

Answer (score 0):

Use ion-list

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let element of results; let i = index" no-lines>
   <ion-item>Index: {{ i }} - Text: {{ element }}  
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```